# Handle Multiple Throwable In A Catch Block In JAVA

Tags: java, performance, optimization, coding-efficiency

I throw multiple errors from my sub and nested methods. Different types of exception are coming from them. *For example:"NullPointer Exception,Connect Exception,IllegalState Exception"* . I can catch them with multiple catch blocks or multiple if statements in one catch block.

I want to write some clean code.I do not want use duplicate things. Is there any other way or method to implement this.

Comment: Please post the code you have written and then we can suggest the changes.

Comment: If you don't want duplicate code in various catch blocks, then you can catch Throwable, which is extended as Error and Exception. But that assumes you really, *really* want to do the same thing for all types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is collapsing multiple `catch` blocks together. This has been possible at least since Java 8.

Here's an example of catching three different exception types and handling them all in the same way:

```
try {
    // do things here
} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalStateException | ConnectException e) {
    // handle exceptions here
}
```

You can have multiple collapsed `catch` blocks, too. Here's an example:

```
try {
    // do things here
} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalStateException | ConnectException e) {
    // handle exceptions here
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
    // handle these exceptions differently from the first set
}
```

Comment: I want warn users with different messages for different exceptions. for example;
For Connect Exception "Connection failed"
For NullPointer Exception "Can not be null"

Comment: @YusufErdoğan There should be no `NullPointerException` thrown as they're all bugs. You wrote that you can't fix all problems, but your users won't do it either. For bugs, I'd show them just "Oops, something went wrong." and send a report to myself, so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think of Exceptions in two categories: Ones that you need to fix, and ones that your users need to fix.

So if you are getting a NullPointerException, this is something you should fix.

Likewise, in the case of ConnectException, this is probably something to report to the user. This isn't a programming problem, it's a networking one.

Comment: I think same. However working on big project. We can not fix all problems and We wan't warn users correctly